# Part of numpy and scipy will not install on Windows due to missing source

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

conda install numpy

ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_actions(337): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::tqdm-4.38.0-py_0'. CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist.

conda install scipy

ERROR conda.core.link:_execute_actions(337): An error occurred while installing package 'defaults::tqdm-4.38.0-py_0'. CondaError: Cannot link a source that does not exist.

conda clean –packages   did not help

Comment: have you tried using pip instead?

Comment: Try this: `conda install -c anaconda numpy`, `conda install -c anaconda scipy`

Comment: I tried both of the above, neither worked.